# cannot import a project into github

Tags: flutter, github

I want to add a flutter project to github so I created a new repository and followed all the instructions in the quick setup and everything was okay but when I opened the repository there were only the read me file with the informations from my project but this is just it no other folders
and by the way I'm trying to import the defult flutter project I didn't change anything

Comment: you are sure you made a commit and pushed to the remote branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may have missed the initial commit of the project.

You would run

```
$ flutter create project
$ cd project/
$ git init
$ git remote add origin GITHUB_REPO_URL
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
$ git push
```

Comment: thank you I did it but the last one gave me an error about upstreaming and origin and when I tried the code in the error it worked , what is upstreaming ?

Comment: Was it something like git push origin master? My apologies. You can read more about upstreaming and downstreaming here: https://www.javatpoint.com/git-upstream-and-downstream.

Comment: it was that git push --set-upstream origin master I tried git push origin master now and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed out on your initial commit of the entire project